# Covariation of Ito semimartingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, correlation, martingale, covariance

If we have two Ito semimartingales over $[0,T]$:
$$d X_t^i=a^i_tdt+\sigma_t^idW_t^i,\quad i=1,2$$
What is the relationship between
$$\langle X^1,X^2 \rangle_t \quad \text{and} \quad \langle W^1,W^2 \rangle_t, $$
where $\langle \rangle_t$ denotes the quadratic variation? Assuming the correlation coefficient $\rho$ is constant, I think we should have
$$\langle W^1,W^2 \rangle_t=\rho dt$$
while if it's not constant we would have
$$\langle W^1,W^2 \rangle_t=\int_0^t\rho_s ds$$
How is this related to the the quadratic variation of $X^1$ and $X^2$, in the two cases?
Is there any relationship with $\int_0^t\rho_s \sigma_s^1 \sigma_s^2 ds$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\left\langle \int_0^t \sigma_s^1 dW_s^1, \int_0^t \sigma_s^2 dW_s^2\right\rangle &= \int_0^t \sigma_s^1 \sigma_s^2 d\langle W_s^1, W_s^2 \rangle\\
&=\int_0^t \rho_s\sigma_s^1 \sigma_s^2 ds.
\end{align*}